# How to remove the background from this SVG

Tags: svg, graphics

I am new to handling graphics and would appreciate some help.
I purchased this particular EPS and trying to edit it.
I am using Vectr for handling EPS/SVG, however, Vectr was not able to open this EPS (bought from iStock).
Tried Gravit and it failed too. Then I converted the EPS to SVG, using an online converter.

This is the graphic I am dealing with:
[image]

I just want to remove the checkered background. When I opened this SVG in Gravit, the background shows as a path. There are a large number of paths in this graphic.

Could someone advice on how to remove this checkered background using a SVG editor like Gravit.

Thank you.

Comment: what you posted is an PNG not SVG... SVG is just XML so you can open it in any text editor ... if the background is image then just find its `<image ... />` tag and delete it ... if a pattern of rectangles find `<rect .../>` etc anyway the checker board is usually rendered by image viewers to recognize transparent areas and its not present in the image itself so you should check that first... Also IMHO this has nothing to do with programing so +Close ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use one of these graphic editors: Corel Draw or Adobe Illustrator. You can send the file to me, I will send it to you without a background. kuznetsovasasha86@gmail.com